# insert assocative array data into mysql

Tags: mysql

**I have the following twitter data output in an associative array format in php, how can I insert this data into mysql database table. Kindly suggest any way to do this.**

```
Array (
 [created_at] => Fri, 02 Nov 2012 18:15:57 +0000 
[from_user] => VolksblattNews 
[from_user_id] => 828753642 
[from_user_id_str] => 828753642 
[from_user_name] => Volksblatt News 
[geo] => [id] => 2.6443066310356E+17 
[id_str] => 264430663103557632 
[iso_language_code] => de 
[metadata] => Array ( [result_type] => recent ) 
[profile_image_url] => http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2619216207/VB_48x48_reasonably_small_normal.gif 
[profile_image_url_https] => https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/2619216207/VB_48x48_reasonably_small_normal.gif 
[source] => <a Google</a> => Bundesrat Burkhalter verstÃ¤rkt Schweizer Beziehungen zu Burma: RANGUN - Didier Burkhalter hatâ€¦ http://t.co/BF3aX2bY 
[to_user] => 
[to_user_id] => 0 
[to_user_id_str] => 0 [
to_user_name] => )
```

**I got this output from the following program:**

```
 <?php

//a json string

$jsonstring='{


"created_at": "Fri, 02 Nov 2012 18:15:57 +0000", 
   "from_user": "VolksblattNews", 
   "from_user_id": 828753642, 
   "from_user_id_str": "828753642", 
   "from_user_name": "Volksblatt News", 
   "geo": null, 
   "id": 264430663103557632, 
   "id_str": "264430663103557632", 
   "iso_language_code": "de", 
   "metadata": {
    "result_type": "recent"
   }, 
   "profile_image_url": "http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/2619216207/VB_48x48_reasonably_small_normal.gif", 
   "profile_image_url_https": "https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/2619216207/VB_48x48_reasonably_small_normal.gif", 
   "source": "&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.google.com/&quot;&gt;Google&lt;/a&gt;", 
   "text": "Bundesrat Burkhalter verst\u00e4rkt Schweizer Beziehungen zu Burma: RANGUN - Didier Burkhalter hat\u2026 http://t.co/BF3aX2bY", 
   "to_user": null, 
   "to_user_id": 0, 
   "to_user_id_str": "0", 
   "to_user_name": null

}';

$arrayvariable=json_decode($jsonstring,true);

print_r ($arrayvariable);

?>
```

Regards

Comment: please ..format your full array as i have done ....

Comment: there is a awesome solution which one accepted. 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744168/how-to-write-a-good-php-database-insert-using-an-associative-array

Comment: Do you know how relational databases or the SQL language works? Really hard to tell what you want from an answer here. Does the data have a set schema or do you want to know how to serialize arrays?

Comment: Have you already your table? If yes show create table plz

Answer (score 0):

Well depending on the use you could store it in as a json string (in case you want to send it directly to the browser and work with it there) or create a table with all the array values as columns. Then do a insert.

To make a safe the insert or update you have a nice example here using prepared statements and PDO.

http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Insert-and-Update-Statement-Use-Prepared-Statement-P552.html